ER Model Justification
Suggest a database design for an internet forum, where users from across the
world can read, write, and comment on texts on various topics. Your design needs
to support the following.
• The system must support user accounts. Various information about the
users must be stored in the system, including their username, email, and
real name. Users are organised in the system according to a user ID number.
• The forum contains several subforums. Each subforum has a name and a
moderator. The moderator will always be a user of the system.
• Each subforum can be either open or closed. An open subforum can be accessed by everyone. For a closed subforum, only certain users have access
to it, and the system must keep track of these access rights.
• Users can subscribe to a subforum, which means that they get to see posts
in it and are reminded of new posts in the subforum when they login.
• Each subforum contains posts, i.e., texts written by users. Each post has a
unique ID number, and for each post the system keeps track of a title, the
date and time when it was written, the text contents, and the post’s author.
Each post belongs to one and only one subforum.
Is my below ER model reflecting the requirements?

